# Is it possible to migrate all collateral from Pardot to Marketing Cloud seamlessly with an app or some code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, migration, pardot, data-migration

I would like to know if it is possible to migrate everything created in Pardot (Engagement Studios, Content, Files, Campaigns, Lists, Dynamic Lists, etc) seamlessly into the Marketing Cloud when a company is migraiting out of Pardot and into the Marketing Cloud (while retaining Salesforce CRM)?

I haven't been able to find concrete answers to this.

​Thank you - Kalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that there exists a function to mass load the content that you are referencing. For content/files (assuming that you are referring to images/build files/landing pages) you can upload zip packages. The maximum file size for a zipped file you can upload is 2 Megabytes. Image files within the zipped file cannot be larger than 200 Kilobytes each. If you wanted to load lists without having to individually load each list you could create a master list outside of the application and configure queries for each list to assign to specific data extensions. This would still require that you create a data extension for each list and since you would need to create a data extension for each list, it may be quicker just to load the campaign lists directly. You may want to reach out to your account rep and see if there is anything that they can do to help load the content.